# Segmentation fault adding SDL_Surface

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2

I'm trying to add a new SDL_Surface to my whack-a-mole clone code but even if I set it to null it wont let me.

game.h

```
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include<string>
 #include"diglet.h" 
#include <list>

class Game{

public:
    SDL_Window  * window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface * screen = NULL;
    SDL_Surface * background = NULL;
    SDL_Surface * mallet = NULL;
    //SDL_Surface * winS = NULL;//this is the part that seg-faults


    SDL_Rect * malletREct;

    Game();
    int execute();

private:
    bool quit;

    static const int SCREEN_H = 250;
    static const int SCREEN_W = 500;
    SDL_Surface * loadSurface(std::string path);

    bool init();
    bool load();
    void cleanup();
    void loop();
    void renderMallet();
    void renderbg();
    void renderBadies(Diglet dig);
    void evenst(SDL_Event &e, Diglet dig[]);
    void close();

};
```

I havent even added it to the .cpp file yet it causes the seg-fault

game.cpp

```
Game::Game(){
}


//render game graphics
void Game::renderMallet(){
malletREct->h = 70;
malletREct->w = 50;
SDL_BlitSurface(mallet,NULL,screen,malletREct);

}

void Game::renderbg(){
    SDL_BlitSurface(background,NULL,screen,NULL);
}

//load game graphics
bool Game::load(){
    bool success = true;
    background = loadSurface("IMG/gameBoard.gif");
    if(background ==NULL){
        printf("unable to load background");
        success = false;
    }

    mallet = loadSurface("IMG/mallet1.png");
    if(mallet == NULL){
        printf("unable to load mallet");
        success = false;
    }
    /*winS=loadSurface("IMG/win.png");
    if(winS ==NULL){
         printf("unable to load mallet");
        success = false;
    }*/
    return success; 

}

//load a surface
SDL_Surface * Game::loadSurface(std::string path){
SDL_Surface *loader = NULL;
    loader = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
    if(loader==NULL){
        printf("Unable to load surface %s ",path.c_str());
    }
    return loader;
}
//initiate game
bool Game::init(){
    bool success = true;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)<0){
        printf("Unable to start video SDL_ERROR \n%s\n",SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }
    else{
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("MOLE BASH!!",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
        );
        if(window==NULL){
            printf("Unable to create window SDL_ERROR: \n%s\n",SDL_GetError());
            success = false;
        }
        else{
            screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
            if(screen == NULL){
                printf("Unable to load screen SDL_ERROR:\n%s\n",SDL_GetError());
                success = false;
            }
            else{

            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}



void Game::evenst(SDL_Event &e,Diglet dig[]){
     if(e.type ==SDL_QUIT){
        quit =true;
     }

     if(e.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION){
        malletREct->x = e.motion.x-27;
        malletREct->y =e.motion.y-20;
     }
     if(e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
            int width = dig[i].myRect.w + dig[i].myRect.x;
            int height = dig[i].myRect.h + dig[i].myRect.y;
            if(malletREct->x >= dig[i].myRect.x){
                if(malletREct->x<= width){
                    if(malletREct->y >= dig[i].myRect.y){
                        if(malletREct->y <= height){
                            dig[i].die();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
}

void Game::close(){
    SDL_FreeSurface(mallet);

    mallet = NULL;
    SDL_FreeSurface(background);
    background = NULL;
    SDL_FreeSurface(screen);
    screen = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();
 }

 void Game::renderBadies(Diglet dig){
    dig.renderMe(screen);
    //printf("rendering diglet");
 }




int Game::execute(){
    bool win;

    if(!init()){
       printf("unable to initialize");
    }
    else{
        printf("initialized");
        Diglet dig [5]= {Diglet(60,65),Diglet(75,140),Diglet(170,70),Diglet(270,70),Diglet(210,140)};
        if(!load()){
            printf("unable to load");
        }
        else{
            printf("loaded");
            quit = false;
            SDL_Event e;
            while(!quit){
                SDL_ShowCursor(0);
                while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)!=0){
                   evenst(e,dig);
                }
                renderbg();
                for(int i = 0; i< 5;i++){
                    renderBadies(dig[i]);
                }
                renderMallet();
                win=true;
                for(int j = 0; j< 5;j++){
                    if(dig[j].alive ){
                         win=false;
                        printf("still alive\n");
                    }


                }
                 SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
                 if(win){
                    quit= true;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By debugging the code I discovered that the malletRect * I created somehow was causing seg-faults, thaks everypne for your help.
what I did was change the malletRect to a non pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using SDL_image, you should also be initialising it with IMG_Init(). Depending on how you use it, your initialisation code might be:

```
if (!IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_JPG | IMG_INIT_PNG))
    {
        cerr << IMG_GetError() << endl;
    }
```

Other than that, it's not visibly clear what's wrong with the program unless you isolate the problem yourself with breakpoints. At first sight, you're not using winS, and one must ask what it is for.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Perhaps you should answer his question, Wise one.

Comment: The problem is that just writing the "SDL_Surface * winS  = NULL" statement  generates the seg-fault, even if I dont implement it that is what baffles me :(

Comment: Originally I suggested using 'new/delete' instead. Have you tried using nullptr instead?

Comment: I all ready answered this question, apparently  the SDL_rect must not be apointer, I still dont know why though, thanks for helping me anyway